# PHP Min Value in Array Except 0

Tags: php, min, array-filter

Please help me to find out why **array_diff** is not working in the following script extract:

```
$iterator_triple = (int) 3;

while($new_row = $new_response->fetch_assoc()) {

    /*prices written into the end of array*/            
    $prices_listed[] = $new_row['price'];
    $prices_listed[] = $new_row['test'];
    $prices_listed[] = $new_row['bpc'];
    $prices_length = count($prices_listed);


    while($iterator_triple < $prices_length + 1) {
        $candidates = array($prices_listed[$iterator_triple - 3], $prices_listed[$iterator_triple - 2], $prices_listed[$iterator_triple - 1]);
        print_r($candidates);
        $min_varan[] = min(array_diff($candidates, array(0)));
        $iterator_triple = $iterator_triple + 3;
    }
}
```

I was planning to rewrite **$candidates** array each loop and fill **$min_varan** array with minimum value of **$candidates** array except 0. But neither array_diff nor array_filter working for me, *zero always stays in and my min function simply picks it*. Point at my error.

You can assume that during first loop:
    *$candidates = array(18000, 19000, 0);*

And during second loop:
    *$candidates = array(26000, 25000, 24000);*

Thereby, *$min_varan[0] = 0*, while I would like to see *18000* instead.

Comment: Are your returned values in $candidates also of type int/float, or may they be strings? so "0" !== 0 ?

Comment: Well, I tried array_diff($candidates ,array('0')) also - didn't help.

Comment: my tests worked. Maybe there is a triple in your code, that is array(0, 0, 0), so min(array(0,0,0)) evaluates to null and this is added to $min_varan anyways?

Comment: @ThomasOster, can you specify a bit more please? What do you mean by 'triple in your code' and array full of zeros? And what did you change exactly for this piece of code to work?

Comment: @ThomasOster, oh excuse me for being such fool, you were right: I just put (int) before each element of $candidates array and everything worked out perfectly. Great thanks!

Comment: Still be sure, that there is no row, where "price","test" and "bpc" are 0, because you are adding the result of min() to $min_varan without checking.

Comment: @ThomasOster, I will check. Merci.

Comment: @Snowman, have you checked?